# Associating changesets that are only relevant to the build definition

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition

I have one team project with multiple solutions in TFS 2012 and also have multiple build definitions that download only relevant sources to build.

I've noticed that each build includes all changesets/work items that have been checked in for other solutions which are not part of the source for the build.

Is there a way to associate changesets/work items that are only relevant to the source for each build definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default association works by linking work items to build based on builds workspace. If a changeset in workspace scope since last build is linked to workitem it will be associated with build. If you cannot limit workspace scope then you will have to introduce custom linking activity and disable the default one.

Comment: Thanks, drk. Your answer gave me a chance to look at the build summary more closely and the associated changesets/work items are correct. There are shared projects in each solution so those shared changesets were being associated with the build.